# Excel 2007 - Get each record by Type from Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have the following Pivot Table from an excel sheet.
Types of Machines: Desktop, Laptop, Server
Numbers represent count of each type for each person.

```
Name         Desktop     Laptop     Server
John               3         1            
Dave                         5           1
Miles              1                     2
```

1) I want each one record per type ( Desktop, Laptop, Server) per Name.
Is there any way to extract that data in Excel 2007?

2) I want to extract data for Desktop and Laptop alone. How do I select those data alone?

Answer (score 0):

Ad 1)

I'm not sure what you mean by "one record per type". Do you want to have a table like this:

```
John - Desktop - 3
John - Laptop - 1
Dave - Laptop - 5
Miles - Desktop - 1
Miles - Server - 2
```

Depending on the data source my guess is that the original data already has this exact form, you just have to delete a couple of columns of extra data that you don't want to see there.

Ad 2)

Directly above the column-header "Desktop" should be a dropdown control. Once you click that you should be able to de-select "Server" (or only select "Desktop" and "Laptop" again depending on the data and the specific layout of the table).